# Share to Messages from Safari fails - missing library

Tags: macos

Any idea how to install the missing library?

```
Process:               Messages Share Extension [39076]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Desktop/Messages.app/Contents/PlugIns/Messages Share Extension.appex/Contents/MacOS/Messages Share Extension
Identifier:            Messages Share Extension
Version:               1.0 (5500)
Build Info:            Messages-743013008000000~82
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Messages Share Extension [39076]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2020-10-15 09:53:44.696 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G2021)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        A02FB4DA-CBA4-4564-EE1E-953BF0A38DA1


Time Awake Since Boot: 1300000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

**Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing**

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

**Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PhotosFormats.framework/Versions/A/PhotosFormats
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/Messages.app/Contents/PlugIns/Messages Share Extension.appex/Contents/MacOS/Messages Share Extension
  Reason: image not found**

Binary Images:
       0x10d85e000 -        0x10d86dff7  com.apple.messages.ShareExtension (1.0 - 5500) <C9509AE7-F4C6-331E-8AEA-FBAA315AC1C1> /Users/USER/Desktop/Messages.app/Contents/PlugIns/Messages Share Extension.appex/Contents/MacOS/Messages Share Extension
       0x1109c4000 -        0x110a55f47  dyld (750.6) <F9D4DEDC-8296-3E3F-B517-9C8B89A4C094> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff310e1000 -     0x7fff31279ffa  com.apple.cloudkit.CloudKit (867 - 867) <1B851180-FC00-357F-B6C1-BB0EA7D6D5CA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/Versions/A/CloudKit
    0x7fff3127a000 -     0x7fff3127afff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.11 - 23) <2F5C8ABA-711F-316C-BB97-921122AEE4DF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff56801000 -     0x7fff569e8ff7  com.apple.imcore (10.0 - 1000) <B5BC3823-0FFA-3D6D-B995-5F674894BF3B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Versions/A/IMCore
    0x7fff56d66000 -     0x7fff56e10fff  com.apple.imsharedutilities (10.0 - 1000) <38235642-07D7-360A-B5C7-FA39B1FD1427> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMSharedUtilities.framework/Versions/A/IMSharedUtilities

Model: iMac17,1, BootROM 428.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i5, 3.3 GHz, 24 GB, SMC 2.34f3
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonR9M395Item, AMD Radeon R9 M395, spdisplays_pcie_device, 2 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384B54463531323634485A2D314739453220
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435438473353313836444D2E4D313646500
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384B54463531323634485A2D314739453220
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435438473353313836444D2E4D313646500
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x14A), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1615.1)
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.6f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi 2, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD ST2000DM001, 2 TB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
USB Device: 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
USB Device: Game Drive
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: My Book 111D
USB Device: 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
USB Device: Back-UPS RS1000G FW:868.L5 -P.D USB FW:L5 -P
USB Device: 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB-Serial Controller
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: HD Pro Webcam C920
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 28.1
```

Comment: Generally speaking you can't really install low level OS components like that unless you have an identical Mac with the same OS and copy between them. Have you tried applying the current Combo update for Catalina?

Comment: Actually, since you're using 10.15.6 there's an update 10.15.7 available. Please install this and try to share again.

Comment: The behavior is unchanged after updating to 10.15.7.  IIRC this has been happening for quite a while - likely in Mojave as well.

Answer (score 1):

User error - I had an older version of Messages that was being opened on login.  When I used the version in the Applications folder Share worked correctly.